# How to restrict user to add input duplicate data into database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'd One text_box(txtname) & Add button in View . I've to restrict user to add already existing(duplicate) data in a database . after clicking on Add button. what changes should I've to do in Model & controller.
 I tried to copy+ paste my model & controller code but due to some restrictions of website i'm not getting able to display code. please kindly suggest me what should I've to do ?[image: Model]

Comment: Hi. It's not really clear what you're asking (and what the problem that you encountered is). Could you please elaborate further?

Comment: Sir , in short user should not enter same product name in a database product table  . If product name is already exist in a database it should popup message "data already exist" .& if data is not in a database table it should get submitted in a database product table

Comment: Are you using ajax submit to post data or simple Post?

Comment: simple post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function insertMenurecord()
{
$this->load->model('CrudModel');     
$this->form_validation->set_rules('txtMenuItem', 'Menu','required|is_unique[tbl_menumaster.menu_name]'); 
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp  Inserted record already exist');  
redirect('Welcome/displayMasterMenu');  
}
else
{
$this->CrudModel->saveMenudata();
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg','You have successfully Inserted record');       
redirect('Welcome/displayMasterMenu');
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this i hope it will help you.
first of all get data by textAddItem

//controller  save data function

//get txtAdditem

```
$txtAddItem = $this->modelname->method_name($this->input->post('textAddItem'));
                    if (count($txtAddItem) > 0) {
                       //already existed
                    }
    else{
    $data=array(
    $name=>$this->input->post('textAddItem')
    );
    return $query=$this->db->insert('tbl_category',$data);
    }
```

//modele

```
function method_name($textAddItem) {
        return $this->db->where('cat_name', $textAddItem)
                        ->get('tbl_category')->row_array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check the `cat_name` in the DB before inserting in the controller

**Controller**

```
public function function_name(){

   $this->load->model('CrudModel');
   $data = array('cat_name' => $name);
   $if_exists = $this->CrudModel->check_category($data);
   if($if_exists > 0){
       //Already Exists
    }else{
       //New insertion
    }
 }
```

**Model**

```
public function check_category($data){
   return $this->db->get_where('tbl_cateogry', $data)->num_rows();
}
```